# Parse JSON Array PHP - String and Float

Tags: php, arrays, json

Cant seem to figure out how to parse the items from this JSON array separately.

JSON:

```
    "data": [
    [
        "2015-02-20",
        2.6105
    ],
    [
        "2015-02-19",
        2.6415
    ],
    [....],
```

Using the below I get both 2015-02-20 and 2.6105.  I would like to be able to parse both the string and the float separately, but cant figure it out.

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($obj['data'] as $data){
     foreach ($data as $value) {
         echo $value;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through the array of data and then looping through each inner array, but only echoing the array as a single object. Instead, try with the indexes of the values like below.

```
foreach($obj['data'] as $data){
    foreach($data as $value){
        echo $value[0];
        echo $value[1];
    }
}
```

The extra `for` loop through the data `foreach($data as $value)` treats the whole array as one object unless you break it up further by specifying the array position, or another loop.